# `npm install <folder>` or `npm pack` does not install dependencies

Tags: coffeescript, npm

I have an npm package that uses coffeescript source, which I want to precompile before `pack` or `publish`. However, my prepublish script depends on coffee-script as a devDependency, but npm isn't installing it before running the prepublish action. I have to run `npm install` separately first, which seems wrong. The same issue exists if I try to `npm install` the source folder into a different project.

I suspect that I'm "doing it wrong," but the only other guidence I've seen is to compile on install rather than publish. I'd rather not do that, so I'm hoping there are examples of prepublish compilation that I can crib from.

Comment: Good question -- seems like a possible npm oversight and might be worthy of opening a pull request on github. The [other](https://github.com/codeparty/racer/blob/master/scripts/prepublish) [examples](https://github.com/santoshrajan/lispyscript/blob/master/package.json#L27) of prepublish I found that do compiling certainly assume that "executable X" already exists (i.e. `npm install` has been executed either locally or globally. This seems kind of strange.